# Angular 2 - how does a component recognize a URL change?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

Using Angular 2, I have a component that subscribes to a service based on the URL hash. No subcomponents are called by the URL change. I assume this would require Route, though Location might be more appropriate. How do I listen and react to a pop state event?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to listen to route changes you can use the Router.

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {Router} from '@angular/router'

export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(router:Router, private location:Location) {
    router.changes.subscribe(() => this.routeChanged());
  }

  private routeChanged():void {
    var path:string = this.location.path();
    console.log("Path:" + path);
  }
}
```

Is this what you wish to do?

Comment: Where did you find Router.changes()? It's not listed in the [Router documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Router-class.html)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b30ddfbfc5192f526ceaac525cf6965635831c46/modules/%40angular/router/src/router.ts#L74. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-interface.html also shows "`changes : Observable<void>`
An observable or url changes from the router."

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer when I run the above code I get an error. Is the code crafted correctly? I am running version 2.0.0-beta.9.

`TypeError: router.changes is undefined`

Comment: the given example is angular2-rc1 before it was like  `router.subscribe(results => this.routeChanged(results));  private routeChanged(path:string):void {
        console.log("New Route:" + path); } ` You were able to get the currunt route from method-parameters, since angular2-rc0 i think it changed and u only get a void method-header. so i was injecting Location

Comment: @Sebastian switching to only using `router.subscribe()` throws `TypeError: instruction is null`. Perhaps a better way of approaching this problem is explaining how to add instructions to Route. Can you recommend an up-to-date tutorial?

Comment: i created a plunker with angular version 2.0.0-beta.9 example of router and subscribing to the route change event. http://plnkr.co/edit/veSOXF0rJyU6hYkqKtJW?p=preview i hope this can help you. if this is not waht you want i cant answer your question :(

Comment: Looks like the code is outdated. I've added a currently valid solution with Angular4: http://jsfiddle.net/85yhu618/

If you need the real url, 
import Router and use this.router.routerState.snapshot.url);